# how to I connect bind attach a naked boolean type to a checkbox in windows presentation foundation c# code behind

Tags: c#, binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, attached-properties

how do I bind/connect/attach or otherwise make a checkbox directly change the boolean value of a variable without writing a wrapper for the boolean function in c#?
Q
I have been writing c# code behind for various events related to a checkbox, specifically events loaded, check, uncheck.

Is there a better way? I will have dozens and dozens of boolean vars in a WPF project. How can I not have a mountain of code specific for each checkbox and each event for each checkbox?

Comment: how about showing the actual code in question here so that we can see what it is you are trying to do..

Comment: I don't want to write ANY more code for each new boolean; or can I do something to have a default or implicit code behind for each boolean.

Comment: I make a simple solution as I dig more into this. Think of dozens and dozens of run-time options in a project. Each gets a check box.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the 'IsChecked' property of you control to a property in your class.

xaml: `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyCheck}"/>`

codebehind: `public bool MyCheck { get; set; }`

you will also need to set the DataContext in your class constructor: `this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Working like a charm! Will post an example.